# TypeScript relative path does not resolve to index file

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I'm working on a project and I set up absolute path imports in my project. But, it doesn't resolve to the index file if I put only up to the folder name.

```
src
 |--modules
      |--search
           |--utils.ts
           |--index.ts
```

When I import,
`import { something } from 'modules/search/index'`
it works fine.

But, I when I import like
`import { something } from 'modules/search'`
It says, `src/modules/search.ts` not found.

Following is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

The expected behavior is,
`import { something } from 'modules/search'` should resolve to `src/modules/search/index.ts`

`import { something } from 'modules/search/utils'` should resolve to `src/modules/search/utils.ts`

Comment: did you try --experimental-specifier-resolution=node flag?

Comment: Tried just now. Not worked... :(

Comment: I had the same issue with typescript and node , and this flag helped me, tsc && node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./build/server.js

Comment: "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

Comment: Can you add this to your index.ts file: `export { Utils } from './utils';`

Comment: @UtkuDemir It's just a tactic to overcome this issue. But, not solving the root cause.